# Your average speed must be twice that of the first lap

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Edit: the problem would've gone something like (I saw it years ago): "find the speed you must run on a second lap around the same track in order to double your average speed for the 2 laps combined."

I have 2 approaches to this problem that give different answers, in both cases we let

$v_1=$ velocity of first lap, $v_2=$ be the velocity of 2nd,

$t_1=$ time of 1st lap, $t_2=$ time of 2nd, and

$d=$ distance of *1 lap*, $v_a=$ average speed.

**First approach:** $$v_a=\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}=\frac{\frac{d}{t_1}+\frac{d}{t_2}}{2}$$

we want this to equal $$2v_1=\frac{2d}{t_1}$$

solving: $$\frac{\frac{d}{t_1}+\frac{d}{t_2}}{2}=\frac{2d}{t_1}$$
$$\frac{d}{t_1}+\frac{d}{t_2}=\frac{4d}{t_1}$$
$$\frac{d}{t_2}=\frac{3d}{t_1}$$
$$3dt_2=dt_1$$
$$t_2=\frac{1}{3}t_1$$

**Second approach:** $$v_a=\frac{2d}{t_1+t_2}$$
we want this to equal $$2v_1=\frac{2d}{t_1}$$
solving: $$\frac{2d}{t_1+t_2}=\frac{2d}{t_1}$$
$$t_1+t_2=t_1$$
$$t_2=0$$
Obviously, it's not possible for $t_2$ to be $0$, that would mean infinite speed. How come my first approach had a different conclusion?

Comment: Can you post the compete problem text? Thanks.

Comment: Your first calculation implicitly assumed the two laps took equal times so you could use an arithmetic mean of the speeds; this looks wrong to me.  Your second calculation assumed the two laps were of equal distances so you implicitly took the harmonic mean  of the speeds.  I suspect the second approach was desired, as was the infinite speed in the second lap (if your average speed must be twice that of the first lap, then you use all the total time in the first lap).

Comment: When you average the velocities you need to use the harmonic mean, $v_a=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{v_1}+\frac{1}{v_2}}$, rather than the arithmetic mean. Because each lap is the same distance, the times will not be equal at different velocities.

Comment: @Matteo, I don't really have the original problem because I saw it a while back. It would've been something like: "find the speed you must run on a second lap around the same track in order to double your average speed for the 2 laps combined."

Comment: @Henry where's that assumption? And yes, the distances are the same. You're running around the same track both laps.

Comment: @DreiCleaner so the average speed isn't the sum of them divided by 2 since the velocities are sort of inversely correlated to the times?

Comment: For Superman aficionados, the alternative approach is to spin clockwise, when viewed from above, to travel back in time.

Comment: The *tried and true* approach to the problem is that $$\text{velocity} ~=~ \frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}},$$ so the 2nd approach has to be the correct one.  Therefore, any approach that disagrees with the 2nd approach is **invalid**.

Comment: When I've seen this problem, it is a kind of "trick problem," whose correct answer is the second one—that you must travel infinitely fast on the second lap.  Without the actual wording you originally saw, I have no way of telling whether the problem you saw was that trick problem, but it seems plausible to me. ¶ The error in your first attempt is that you assume that the overall average speed is the average of the speeds on the two laps.  That may sound reasonable, but it is in error, because the average must be done per unit time, not per unit distance.

Comment: (If you were calculating the average "inverse speed"—i.e., the average distance per time—then it would be OK to average that per unit distance.  But that isn't likely to be what's being asked here.)

Comment: Not sure if that is your source, and it's almost certainly not the original source, but this is riddle 3 in this veritasium video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgCXdNhVC1Q&t=138s with "solution" here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72DCj3BztG4&t=164s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the average speed over a path $\gamma_n$ is $$v_n = \frac{d_n}{t_n}$$ where $d_n$ is the length of the path and $t_n$ is the amount of time taken to travel the length of the path. (Subscript $n$ included here so that we can talk about different paths in the same equation.)

Another way to put it, the average speed is $v_n$ such that
$  d_n = v_n t_n. $

A path of two laps has length $d_0 = d_1 + d_2$ where $d_1$ is the length of the first lap and $d_2$ is the length of the second lap.
Of course $d_1 = d_2$ it both laps are around the same track.

So if it takes time $t_1$ to travel the first lap,
and it takes time $t_2$ to travel the second lap, then if the two laps together are traveled at an average speed of $v_0$ in time $t_0$, we have

\begin{align}
d_0 &= v_0 t_0, \\
d_1 + d_2 &= v_0 (t_1 + t_2), \\
v_1 t_1 + v_2 t_2 &= v_0 (t_1 + t_2).
\end{align}

Solving for the average speed $v_0,$

$$ v_0 =  \frac{v_1 t_1 + v_2 t_2}{t_1 + t_2}. $$

This is a *weighted average*. The weights are $t_1$ and $t_2.$
The "heavier" $t_1$ is in comparison to $t_2,$ the more the average $v_0$
will look like $v_1,$ and vice versa.

> **Aside:**
>
> Imagine you have two jobs, the first of which pays $\$10$ per hour and the second of which pays $\$50$ per hour. Your two employers agree to give you $8$ hours total work in one day; the first employer gives you $x$ hours ($0 \leq x \leq 8$) and the other employer gives you $8 - x$ hours.
>
> If $x = 1$ (you work $1$ hour in the first job and $7$ hours in the second), you make $\$360$ that day, which averages to $\$45$/hour for the $8$ hours you worked. But if $x = 7$ you make $\$120$, which averages to $\$15$/hour.
>
> The average rate of pay here is a weighted average, just like the average speed, and clearly the relative sizes of the weights can make a big difference.

If you start with two different speeds $v_1$ and $v_2,$ the only way you can get a weighted average like $\dfrac{v_1 t_1 + v_2 t_2}{t_1 + t_2}$ to come out to $\frac12(v_1 + v_2)$ is to make the two weights equal.
That is, you set $t_2 = t_1$ so that
$$
v_0 = \frac{v_1 t_1 + v_2 t_2}{t_1 + t_2}
= \frac{v_1 t_1 + v_2 t_1}{t_1 + t_1}
= \frac{(v_1 + v_2) t_1}{2t_1}
= \frac{v_1 + v_2}{2}.
$$

Your first approach, by starting with $v_0 = \dfrac{v_1 + v_2}{2},$
is implicitly assuming from the start that $t_1 = t_2.$
And that's a very bad assumption, because while you were guaranteed that the two laps would have the same length, you were *not* guaranteed that they would take the same time to traverse.

In fact, if they *did* take the same time to traverse, you'd have the same speed on each of them, and the average would be $v_1,$ not $2v_1$. That doesn't work at all!

Comment: It helps to think of it as a weighted average, thanks. I understood that it didn’t work, this explains the why

Answer (score 1):

The average speed of the two-lap journey, i.e., the runner's average speed *over* the two laps, $$\frac{2d}{t_1+t_2}\\=\frac{t_1}{t_1+t_2}\left(\frac{d}{t_1}\right)+\frac{t_2}{t_1+t_2}\left(\frac{d}{t_2}\right)\\=\frac{t_1}{t_1+t_2}\,v_1+\frac{t_2}{t_1+t_2}\,v_2,$$ is the ***weighted*** average of the two speeds (their weighted arithmetic mean), proportionally accounting for the lap durations.

> **First approach:** $$v_a=\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}$$

You have instead taken the average of the two lap speeds (their ordinary arithmetic mean).

This equals the average speed *over* the two laps if and only if both laps have the same duration, i.e., $$t_1=t_2.$$

P.S. Your misinterpretation is akin to falsely claiming that the overall performance on an exam comprising several papers and in which every mark is worth the same value (LHS) equals the simple average of the individual scaled scores (RHS). But of course, $$\frac{55+15}{60+100}\ne\frac12\left(\frac{55}{60}+\frac{15}{100}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

I changed the previous answer completely as it was incorrect...

The second approach still stands correct than the first approach.

However, $t_2 = 0$ is incorrect. This is due to the fact that the first average (first lap) cannot be compared in anyway to the final average (both laps). Plot the first average and final average... they require 2 different set of cartesian graphs because the axes of the first average plot are not applicable for the final average.

Simply saying $2v_1 = v_a$ is incorrect as $d_1 ≠ d_1 + d_1$, $d_1 ≠ 2d_1$, which brings the fact that $k * \frac{d_1}{t_1} ≠ \frac{2d_1}{t_1 + t_2}$, and finally ... $k * v_1 ≠ v_a$, where $k = 2$. You are comparing averages over $2$ **different** events/**domains** (might be the difference in distance covered) and you cannot compare them unless you find a way to relate those domains first.

Comment: why is $v_2$ equal to double the average velocity?

Comment: @Cotton Headed Ninnymuggins  sorry i read the question wrong... my bad... let me edit my answer