# Help with average velocity problem

Tags: calculus

Your kite records the height $k(t)$ in meters with the following function:

$k(t) = 4\sqrt{t}\,,$

where $t$ is time in minutes. Find the average vertical velocity of the kite from $t = 4$ to $t = 16$.

So what I did was plug in $4$ and $16$ into $t$.

$k(4) = 4\sqrt{4} = 8$

$k(16) = 4\sqrt{16} = 16$

I then used the average velocity to get $2/3$ meters per minute. Am I right?

Comment: If you are at the point in your course where you are calculating "average rate of change for a function", which is $$   \frac{\Delta k}{\Delta t} \ \ = \ \ \frac{k(t_2) \ - \ k(t_1)}{t_2 \ - t_1} \ \ , $$ then since the average rate of change in the height over the time interval is the average vertical velocity during that interval, your answer is correct.  (This will be the basis for the definition of "derivative of a function", which you would be reaching soon.)

Comment: Don't be so quick to accept answers. We occasionally get really, really horribly wrong answers, one of which you accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the formula $$\text{average velocity} = \frac{\text{displacement, i.e., change in position}}{\text{time elapsed}},$$ the required average velocity is indeed $\displaystyle\frac{16\text{ m}-8\text{ m}}{12\text{ min}}=\frac23$ m/min.

P.S. The average (arithmetic mean) of a continuously-varying quantity over an interval does not generally equal the average of its values at the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: "P.S. The average (arithmetic mean) of a continuously-varying quantity over an interval does not generally equal the average of its values at the endpoints of the interval." I find it very interesting how you answered [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4314547/your-average-speed-must-be-twice-that-of-the-first-lap) about this very thing!

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins Oh thanks for linking to my more detailed answer [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4314833/21813). It wasn't upvoted, so I wasn't sure whether you'd found it useful.

Comment: Sure did, I think your answer sealed the deal actually with the test averages analogy